# MS Access - Run VBA script to OnClick event

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am trying to get a VBA script to run when I click a button on a form in access. I've looked at guides online and they say to press [Event Procedure] on the drop down but I don't seem to have the option to do that. Any ideas?

edit:

Clicking on the three dots just takes me to a screen to enter a macro, I don't get the option to choose.

Thanks!

[image: No options shown on drop down for OnClick]

Answer (score 3):

1. Clear the On Click field (delete the [Embedded Macro] text)
2. After that, click the `...` button.
3. You should see this dialog box :
   [image: dialog box]
4. Choose `Code Builder`.

Enjoy :D

Comment: Hi Parakmiakos,

Thanks for the answer, if I do that rather than getting the above box I get taken to a screen for a Macro. There is no option for VB, can't figure out why! Do I have to enable VB somewhere or something?

Comment: Do the first step, press the delete button on your keyboard, while focusing the On Click field.